# NSRangeException when calling objectAtIndex on NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting this error and I don't understand why:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: ' - [__ NSCFArray objectAtIndex ] : index (171053968) beyond bounds (226)'

```
- (void)makeArrayOfGrade{

    BOOL *alreadyAdded;
    for (int a = 0; a <= [allData count]-1; a++) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:a inSection:0];
        NSDictionary *dict = [allData objectAtIndex:path];

        if ([[dict objectForKey:@"grade"] isEqualToString: @"5 класс"]) {

            /*     for (int i = 0; i <= [allData count]; i++){
             NSIndexPath *inPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
             NSDictionary *inDict = [allData objectAtIndex:path];
             if ([dict objectForKey:@"subject"]==[inDict objectForKey:@"subject"]) {
             added=YES;
             }
             }
             }
             if (added==NO) { */
            [dataForEachGrade addObject:dict];
            NSLog(@"added");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you request an object of `allData` at an index that does not exist. 
I.e., the data in your table view do not fit to `allData`.

Comment: I take allData out of here:
- (void)loadObjectFromPlistFile {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GDZ" ofType:@"plist"];
    allData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

Comment: what I have to do? I might haven't understand..

Comment: @AshVar, also note that objectAtIndex expects an integer but you are passing an NSIndexPath.

Comment: Anna Karenina, thanks! It helped a lot! Now it runs, but I get white screen. It seems that I have just to reload tableView, but it doesn't help... Any suggestions?